# Install Google Play Services without Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-play-services

Is it *legally* possible to install Google Play Services onto a device which does not have the Google Play Store? I have a device that only has the Android Market, and given certain constraints I'm not able to update the device.

I ask about legality because I've seen a couple comments around saying that pushing Google Play Services to an emulator that's not supported is considered piracy.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow is not the best place to ask such questions.

Comment: @MaciejGórski would you recommend I go to the Google forums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a device that only has the Android Market, and given certain constraints I'm not able to update the device

That does not necessarily preclude you from being able to install the Play Services Framework from the Android Market -- search for it and see if it is available. Some devices seem to be able to get it, others not. I have assumed that the filtering is based upon OpenGL ES levels, but there may be more to it than that.

I can state fairly confidently that downloading the Play Store or any other bits of proprietary Google code from Web sites is committing a copyright violation, just as whoever uploaded it committed a copyright violation. There is no public distribution license for those bits; they are only licensed to select hardware manufacturers.

Beyond that, seek qualified legal counsel.

Comment: I wasn't able to find it while searching from the Market, so whatever manifest permissions were specified hid Google Play Services from my results on this device. Thanks for the response. Fortunately requirements ended up getting loosened, and I was able to update the phone.